# Setting CommandBehavior for executing commands in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How can I specify CommandBehavior (for e.g. SequentialAccess) when executing a command on entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If you really want to, you can](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2007/11/15/commandbehavior-sequentialaccess.aspx). As the link shows, however, doing so will cause other problems. I think you would probably get a better answer if you explained what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Certainly helpful in finding out what I wanted.